# R sumif based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to create summary tables based on the sum or average of other columns' values instead of by count.

```
Amount  Age ActualResult    Prediction
100     20  Pass            Pass
200     24  Pass            Pass
300     30  Pass            Fail
400     34  Pass            Fail
500     40  Fail            Pass
600     44  Fail            Pass
700     50  Fail            Fail
800     54  Fail            Fail
```

I can get a table by count using the following code:

```
table(data$ActualResult,data$Prediction)


            Predict Pass    Predict Fail
Actual Pass 2               2
Actual Fail 2               2
```

But I don't know how to get the table by sum of amount or average age:
By Amount:

```
            Predict Pass    Predict Fail
Actual Pass 300             700
Actual Fail 1100            1500
```

By Avg Age:

```
            Predict Pass    Predict Fail
Actual Pass 22              32
Actual Fail 42              52
```

What code would I use to create the tables by amount and average age?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `questionr` package

```
questionr::wtd.table(
  data$ActualResult,
  data$Prediction,
  weights = data$Amount
)
#>      Fail Pass
#> Fail 1500 1100
#> Pass  700  300
```

To get the average age, divide by the original table

```
questionr::wtd.table(
  data$ActualResult,
  data$Prediction,
  weights = data$Age
) / table(data$ActualResult,data$Prediction)
#>      Fail Pass
#> Fail   52   42
#> Pass   32   22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` way, using your data as `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# sum of Amount
sum_amount <-
  df %>%
  group_by(ActualResult, Prediction) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(Amount)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Prediction", 
              values_from = "sum", 
              names_prefix = "Predict")

# average Age
avg_age <-
  df %>%
  group_by(ActualResult, Prediction) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Age)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Prediction", 
              values_from = "avg", 
              names_prefix = "Predict")
```